# ZF2 how to populate a form that failed a POST request into a GET redirect

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm following REST standard where you use a `POST` action to create a resource and `GET` to show data.

That includes using `GET` to show a creation form and `POST` to handle the actual creation of the resource (AKA, saving to database).

In the case the `POST` request fails (lets say, a duplicate email address), a `302` is returned as a response, redirecting the user back to the form (kind of as a `GET /resource/create` with `302`).

How do I persist the data sent from `POST` after the redirection in ZF2?

Or, maybe ZF2 doesn't support this/we're not supposed to do a 302 redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just think you want to pass data back to form. And display data on each fields. Usually, for failed request you don't need make `redirection`. Just display the `form` and `data`. Just use redirect when the process success (saving to database).

```
$form = new Form(); // your form
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ($request->isPost()) {
    $form->setData($request->getPost());
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // saving data here then redirect
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('route', array('action' => 'name'), array('param => 1'));
    } 
}

return array('form' => $form);
```